# Multiline graph in PDF file using ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to give export option in my application that will export PDF file and it should consist multi-line graph. How can i do this in ruby on rails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my application, i am using `Highcharts`.

I have found great success in rendering `charts to pdf` using a combination of 2 gems:

`wicked_pdf` - https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf

and

`wkhtmltopdf-binary` - https://github.com/zakird/wkhtmltopdf_binary_gem

The second is the binary dependency for wicked_pdf.

It can render your rails view in pdf format.

**Edit:**

I have used PDFkit as well, code is given below from my controller method:

Onclick of `"Download PDF"` button:

```
      if params[:commit]=="Download PDF"
        html = render_to_string(:layout => false , :action => "controller_name/pdf_chart_erb_file.html.erb")
        kit = PDFKit.new(html)
        kit.stylesheets << "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css"
        send_data(kit.to_pdf, :filename => "my_chart.pdf", :type => 'application/pdf', :disposition => 'inline')
        file = kit.to_file("#{Rails.root}/app/exe.pdf")
      end
```

You can use or render your `graphs` in `pdf_chart_erb_file.html.erb`, it simply converts all your `html file to PDF` file as per code given above.

Comment: Actually it will create pdf file for HTML view, I want some texts(Database values) and n number of graphs in one pdf file. would it help me?

Comment: Yes, it might be helpful to you. I have used it in my application.

Comment: Im trying to install it.. I have installed wicked_pdf, ekhtmltopdf_binary and Pdfkit.. But how to update config files in application and how to save it in vendor/plugins path of application dont know..

Comment: In ur solution action => "pdf_chart_erb_file.html.erb", action is view file name? suppose if i want to call action of another controller then?

Comment: Here you go, in 'html = render_to_string(:layout => false , :action => "controller_name/pdf_chart_erb_file.html.erb")' see my updated answer.

Comment: yes i did this and its working.. But tell me one thing render_to_string only works with view part i means what if i want to execute its action then coreesponding view?

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer, also in your case you will have to write the action and then render it to your corresponding view.

Comment: My code is generating graph from JS would it work? and second thing how can i write action? Its not calling action anymore..:(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31322/discussion-between-sim-and-sumit-munot)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your situation, and what content you already have (if any) which you want to render your PDF based on. Some existing options are:

- [PDFKit](https://github.com/pdfkit/PDFKit), which can create PDFs based on your existing HTML documents
- [Prawn](http://prawn.majesticseacreature.com), which is a lightweight Ruby API for creating PDFs

Some options (like PDFKit above, and also [Wicked PDF](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf)) will rely on an external tool like [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) to render existing HTML pages as PDFs, whereas other options (like Prawn) are more Ruby native, so it really depends on your situation which path your should take in your application.

As for the graph you mentioned, if you already have it being rendered as an image file, it might be easiest to use one of the HTML-to-PDF generation options, but if you're wanting to render the graph custom in the PDF context and don't already have it as a standalone image, something like Prawn may be best.